# Python/Pandas/Datetime: transform entire lists in a column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, lambda

I have a Pandas Dataframe with following structure:

```
   title                       zeiten
0  Anker der Liebe             ['2020-02-17T19:15:00+01:00']
1  DarkroomTödliche Tropfen    ['2020-02-17T21:45:00+01:00']
2  Das geheime Leben der Bäume,['2020-02-13T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-14T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-15T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-16T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-17T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-18T16:45:00+01:00', '2020-02-19T16:45:00+01:00']
...
```

i want to transform the column 'zeiten' to datetime so i tride:

```
df['zeiten'] = df['zeiten'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)[0])
```

This works for row 0 and 1, but not for row 2, since only the first date of the list is transformed, so the output looks like this:

```
   title                        zeiten
0  Anker der Liebe              2020-02-17 19:15:00+01:00
1  DarkroomTödliche Tropfen     2020-02-17 21:45:00+01:00
2  Das geheime Leben der Bäume  2020-02-13 16:45:00+01:00
```

is there a way to transform entire lists in a column to Datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert all values, not only first, so removed `[0]` and also if necessary converted DatetimeIndex for each value to `list`:

```
df['zeiten'] = df['zeiten'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
print (df)
                          title  \
0               Anker der Liebe   
1      DarkroomTodliche Tropfen   
2  Das geheime Leben der Baume,   

                                              zeiten  
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-17 19:15:00+01:00'], d...  
1  DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-17 21:45:00+01:00'], d...  
2  DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-13 16:45:00+01:00', '2...
```

---

```
df['zeiten'] = df['zeiten'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tolist())
print (df)
                          title  \
0               Anker der Liebe   
1      DarkroomTodliche Tropfen   
2  Das geheime Leben der Baume,   

                                              zeiten  
0                        [2020-02-17 19:15:00+01:00]  
1                        [2020-02-17 21:45:00+01:00]  
2  [2020-02-13 16:45:00+01:00, 2020-02-14 16:45:0...
```